# same libvirt config, one machine boots, the other does not

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt

I am migrating a bunch of vms from an old machine to a new one.
The old one was using some in-house scripts and lvm logical volumes, the new one uses libvirt and plain files. The configs are rather uniform, but some of the vms run flawlessly on new machine, while I just cannot get others to work. The symptom is that after loading the initial ramdisk, I see the screen where bios states that "Booting from hard disk".

A good vm in the old machine:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -name airesisdb -smp 1 -m 1024 -vnc 127.0.0.1:10 -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:10010,server,nowait -daemonize -localtime -usb -usbdevice tablet -net tap,ifname=vm-airesisdb,script=no -net nic,macaddr=02:13:37:00:00:10,model=virtio -rtc base=utc,clock=host,driftfix=slew -pidfile /var/run/kvm/airesisdb.pid -boot c -drive index=0,media=disk,if=virtio,boot=on,file=/dev/vg/airesisdb,cache=writeback -drive index=1,media=disk,if=virtio,file=/dev/vg/airesisdb_2,cache=writeback
```

A "bad vm" in the old machine (running there perfectly):

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -name tomcat -smp 1 -m 1024 -vnc 127.0.0.1:12 -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:10012,server,nowait -daemonize -localtime -usb -usbdevice tablet -net tap,ifname=vm-tomcat,script=no -net nic,macaddr=02:13:37:00:00:12,model=virtio -rtc base=utc,clock=host,driftfix=slew -pidfile /var/run/kvm/tomcat.pid -boot c -drive index=0,media=disk,if=virtio,boot=on,file=/dev/vg/tomcat,cache=writeback
```

The libvirt xml of the good vm in the new machine:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='34'>
  <name>airesisdb</name>
  <uuid>c591e02e-44f4-0098-4656-fb0acca557fb</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='i686' machine='pc-1.1'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writeback'/>
      <source dev='/var/vm-storage/airesisdb'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writeback'/>
      <source dev='/var/vm-storage/airesisdb_2'/>
      <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:74:65:bd'/>
      <source network='public'/>
      <target dev='vm-airesisdb'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5905' autoport='yes'/>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='none'/>
</domain>
```

The bad vm on the new machine, behaving badly:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='46'>
  <name>tomcat</name>
  <uuid>12059a28-ad19-a4fe-fa71-0af26b8cbb3e</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='i686' machine='pc-1.1'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writeback'/>
      <source dev='/var/vm-storage/tomcat'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writeback'/>
      <source dev='/var/vm-storage/tomcat'/>
      <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'> 
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:4b:18:31'/>
      <source network='private'/>
      <target dev='vm-tomcat'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5906' autoport='yes'/>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='none'/>
</domain>
```

The good vm runs this inside:

```
Linux airesisdb 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The bad vm runs this inside:

```
Linux sso.edemokraciagep.org 3.16.0-60-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 13:37:48 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

old host machine runs this:

```
Linux 81.7.14.91 4.0.0-sabayon #1 SMP Fri Apr 17 08:09:22 UTC 2015 x86_64 AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

new host machine runs this:

```
Linux adanarancs 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ii  libvirt-bin                                      0.9.12.3-1+deb7u1             amd64                         programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt0                                         0.9.12.3-1+deb7u1             amd64                         library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
```

I have tried different features, cpu modes, booting different kernels with different options, but no luck.

Any idea what can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: You're using -cpu host in your post, have you tried replicating the exact CPU flags the old machine uses on the new machine, or tried to find a -cpu preset that works on the old machine and then tried it on the new machine?

Comment: Thank you, if you make an answer I will accept it.
The winning configuration:

     <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
       <model fallback='allow'>cpu64-rhel5</model>
    </cpu>

I don't exactly understand the thing,as I am using vanilla ubuntu kernels.
But it does work.

Comment: Strange how vanilla Ubuntu kernels fail to work with the new configuration, usually this is only an issue when software is compiled specifically for your hardware. I've seen it happen before though, glad my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post you are using `-cpu host` on both the old and the new machine.
While generally this shouldn't be a problem when migrating VMs, especially if the new machine has a newer same-brand CPU than the old one.
However, in some cases this can still cause issues.

You can try to manually specify the CPU type on the new machine to a CPU type that matches the old machine, or find a CPU type on the old machine that works and then use it on the new machine.
You may not gain all the benefits of the new hardware of the new machine this way, but at least the VM will be working on the new machine, and if you choose the right CPU type it should, at the very least, be on par with the old machine.